# Trying to combine 3 byte[] with bytebuffer but fails with offset

Tags: java, android, arrays, byte

I trying to combine 3 byte arrays to one big. I use bytebuffer to make it work. It works when I dont use the offset.

So I have 3 bytearrays and want to skip the first 44 bytes in the first byte array. The size of it is 48044. The code works when I dont uses offset, as soon as I use it it fails to do the first put. I cant see what I miss here.

```
    byte[] combined = new byte[wavData.length - 44 + gap.length + toneArray.length];
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(combined);
    byteBuffer.put(wavData, 44, wavData.length);
    byteBuffer.put(gap);
    byteBuffer.put(toneArray, 0, toneArray.length);
```

Comment: try this `byteBuffer.put(wavData, 44, wavData.length - 44)`

Comment: @JVic Thanks it works now did miss that little thing.